# Draw custom region Google maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible to draw a custom region using the Android Google maps API? 
The currently available tiles in google maps are missing some information and I was wondering if it is possible to draw custom shapes on top of the Map using overlays?

Also do overlays occupy an entire layer on top of the existing map, or do they only occupy the region which is encompassed in the draw method?

I want only the custom drawn region(if possible) to be interactive to user touches and hence need only the drawn region to respond in a certain manner to user touches/gestures.

Help appreciated.